# How can I remove support for view engines that I don't use?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

It's my understanding that:

> in debug mode, you can increase performance by removing support for view engines that you are not actually using (e.g. WebForms)

I'd like to do this for my application as the only view engine I use is Razor. How can I do this?

Answer (score 19):

Place this in the Application_Start method in Global.asax.cs:

```
ViewEngines.Engines.Clear();
ViewEngines.Engines.Add(new RazorViewEngine());
```

Comment: Can you please explain what are the benefits of clear the engines list, and what is in this list by default?

Comment: @gdoron: By default, this has a WebFormsViewEngine and a RazorViewEngine.

Comment: And what are the benefits of remove the WebFormsViewEngine (which I don't use)?

Comment: @gdoron I use the Spark view engine so if I leave the WebForms engine registered it prevents some "view not found" messages from occurring correctly.

Comment: @Ryan, I think it's all cached, so the benefits are very small, am I wrong?

Comment: @gordon Yes everything is cached. I just wanted to mention that there is weird behavior in Spark (bug?) if you leave the WebForms view engine registered but don't use it.

Comment: Is there any way to prevent Razor or WebForms from being registered in the first place?

Comment: this will search for `.vbhml` to remove that , use **Custom Razor View Engine**  check [this](http://www.dotnet-tricks.com/Tutorial/mvc/NcJP200113-Custom-Razor-View-Engine-for-C#-and-VB.html)

Answer (score 9):

In your `Application_Start`:

```
ViewEngines.Engines.Remove(
    ViewEngines.Engines.OfType<WebFormViewEngine>().First()
);
```

Comment: What are the benefits? all the views routes cached in the memory, aren't they?

Comment: @gdoron, yes, in Release mode they are. In Debug mode they aren't.

Comment: BTW, It's better to be more specific and write instead of First - **Single** , and maybe **SingleOrDefault** is even better.